# Compilation of Mozilla NSS is failing on VS 2019

Tags: visual-studio-2019, nss

Compilation of Mozilla NSS is failing on VS 2019

Compilation of Mozilla NSS is failing on VS 2019.

Here are the steps I followed:

- Installed VS 2019
- Installed MINGW for make on Windows
- Installed CYGWIN
- Downloaded nss-3.38
- Open Command Prompt:
- "C:\PROGRA~2\MICROS~1\2019\Professional\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat" amd64
- Open the Mozilla Shell:
- C:\mozilla-build\start-shell.bat
- set following variables
- export MOZ_NO_RESET_PATH=1
- export NSS_DISABLE_GTESTS=1
- export HOME=/c/PATROLTPS/1.2.00/src
- export BUILD_OPT=1
- export OS_TARGET=WINNT`
- make nss_build_all
- 

$ make nss_build_all

mkdir -p ./../nspr/WINNT1.0.18(0.48/3/2)_x86_64_64_OPT.OBJ

/bin/sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('

/bin/sh: -c: line 0: `mkdir -p ./../nspr/WINNT1.0.18(0.48/3/2)_x86_64_64_OPT.OBJ'

make: *** [../nspr/WINNT1.0.18(0.48/3/2)_x86_64_64_OPT.OBJ/config.status] Error 2

Can anyone please let me know if the compilation is successful on VS 2019?